# Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{z^2+i}$ at $z=i$

Tags: laurent-series

I want to find the Laurent series of $1\over(z^2+i)$at $z=i$. How do I start and go on from there? Do I start with either of these?

$$1 \over{(z+i\sqrt i)(z-i\sqrt i)}$$

$$\frac{1}{i} \frac{1}{1+(z^2/i)}$$

[answer for this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElPI7.jpg)

Comment: First do partial fractions. If we abbreviate $w=(1-i\sqrt2)/2$, then the zeros of $z^2+i$ are $w$ and $-w$. Then you can find constants $A$ and $B$ such that
$$\frac1{z^2+i}=\frac A{z-w}+\frac B{z+w}.$$ Then you can write the denominators in the form $C+D(z-i)$ (different values of $C,D$ for the two terms), and manipulate that to a form where you can use the geometric series sum formula.

Comment: given answer is https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElPI7.jpg
and For my solution that is laurent expansion of  1/z^2 at z=i 
so I think this is wrong question
but im doing partial fraction for this question and i think it can be solved thx

Comment: given answer is not belong to this question I think

Comment: A typo in my formula for $w$. It should read $w=(1-i)/\sqrt2$ (or some other equivalent form).